# set Number Format by Open Office API

Tags: delphi, openoffice-calc

Is it possible to set number format of cell by Open Office API?
I am exporting some data into OpenOffice calc and I want to use a user defined format.

Below is an example of my code:

```
    try
      AOpenOffice := GetActiveOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        AOpenOffice := CreateOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
      end;
    end;
    AStarDesktop := AOpenOffice.createInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');
    AFileProp := varArrayCreate([0, -1], varVariant);
    AMyDoc := AStarDesktop.LoadComponentFromURL('private:factory/scalc', '_blank', 0, AFileProp);
    AAllSheets := AMyDoc.Sheets;
    AMySheet := AAllSheets.getByIndex(0);

    for AColumn := 0 to 9 do begin
      for ARow := 1 to 10 do begin
        ARange := Chr(ord('A') + AColumn) + IntToStr(ARow);
        AMyCell := AMySheet.getCellRangeByName(ARange);
        AValue := (AColumn + 1) * ARow * 1000;
        AMyCell.setFormula(AValue);
        // ? TODO set number format
      end;
    end;
```

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Check [this article](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Formatting_Spreadsheet_Documents), specifically *Number, Date and Text Format* paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `ActivateSheetByIndex(1).getCellByPosition(col - 1, row - 1).NumberFormat := 36; {Date}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.